# Can I edit hyperledger composer transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am using Hyperledger composer V0.16.0 and fabric 1.0. Can I edit or update the transaction which is posted using composer swagger API without changing the transaction ID? If possible means can anyone please share sample .cto file for reference to edit the transaction.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No you can't edit a submitted transaction - that's the point of a blockchain. Transactions submitted using Composer/Fabric are immutable and can't be changed after submission. If you want to make a change, you have to submit a new transaction to update the ledger.

I hope that helps clarify things.